# How to compile a list of strings by matching multiple columns across dataframes?

Tags: r

I've got a very challenging problem and have no clue how to approach it.  (I'm not even sure I titled the thread appropriately.)  Anyhow, I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), state = structure(1:4, .Label = c("d", 
"m", "o", "q"), class = "factor"), city = structure(1:4, .Label = c("h", 
"n", "p", "r"), class = "factor"), value = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 4L), 
    source = structure(1:4, .Label = c("string1", "string2", 
    "string3", "string4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("country", 
"state", "city", "value", "source"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))


df2 <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c"), class = "factor"), state = structure(1:4, .Label = c("d", 
"e", "f", "g"), class = "factor"), city = structure(1:4, .Label = c("h", 
"i", "j", "k"), class = "factor"), mean_value = 1:4, level_of_mean = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("city", "country"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("country", 
"state", "city", "mean_value", "level_of_mean"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Both dataframes contain data for various countries, states, and cities.  Dataframe `df1` contains "raw" data, which dataframe `df2` contains means calculated from values in `df1` at various levels (country, state, and city) depending on data availability (either city-level, state-level, or country-level means, in that order of preference).

What I need to do is this: for each `mean_value` in `df2`, I need to use the associated `level_of_mean`, `country`, `state`, and `city` to look in `df1` and using `country`, `state`, and `city`, build a list of the strings from column `source`.  For the dataframes above, this would yield the following result:

```
source <- structure(1:4, .Label = c("string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"
), class = "factor")
```

Does anyone have any idea of how I might approach this, frankly i'm not even sure where to begin!

**EDIT:** I should also note that my "real" dataframes contain many different `mean_value` and `level_of_mean` columns, so a general solution would be best.

Comment: Did you mean "for each *row* in `df2`" or "for each *unique value of* `mean_value` in `df2`"?

Comment: Hey Chris, apologies for the confusion, I meant for each row.

Comment: If I understand correctly, each of the four words in `source` corresponds to a row in `df2`.  Hence `df[,2]` corresponds to `"string2"`. It looks like `df2[,2]` has a `mean_value` of `2` for `country` `"a"`.  But there are two rows in `df1` that have `"a"` in the `country` field (rows 1 and 2).  So how to you choose one row or the other, i.e. why choose `"string2"` over `"string1"`?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your help. Column "level_of_mean" indicates the "resolution" of the means. For df2[1,] the mean = 1 was calculated at the city level (since df1 contains that resolution of data). However, for df2[2,] the mean = 2 was calculated at the country level (since there are no city and state level data in df1).  Does that make sense?  Thus, the source for df2[1,] is "string1" and the sources for df2[2,] are both "string1" and "string2".  I just want to make a list of all sources (since the real df1 contains much extraneous data that aren't in df2). hope it is clear!

Comment: Yes that's clear now.  You want `source` to be a list of unique values from the `source` column of `df1`.

Comment: Hello Chris, just to clarify, the values in df2 were calculated from a much larger df1 that contains many other country/state/city combinations (as well as many other "sources" that weren't used to calculate df2).  I only want a list of the sources that correspond to the data in df2, so just listing the unique values from the source column of df1 wouldn't work - that would result in many non-associated sources being included.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it makes sense, and I figured as much.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>%
  select(-mean_value) %>%
  gather(level, value, -level_of_mean) %>%
  filter(as.character(level_of_mean) == as.character(level)) %>%
  select(-level_of_mean) %>%
  inner_join(df1 %>% 
               gather(level, value, -source)
             ) %>%
  select(source) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  unlist(use.names=F) %>%
  as.character()
```

You'll see some warnings about factor levels not being identical across country, state, and city, you can safely ignore or suppress them.

If you're not familiar with the chain or pipe operator `%>%` it is implemented by `dplyr`. Basically `x %>% f(y)` is the same thing as `f(x, y)`

But you can do the same thing without that operator:

```
df2 <- select(df2, -mean_value)
df2 <- gather(df2, level, value, -level_of_mean)
df2 <- filter(df2, ...
```

etc.

These are `dplyr` functions.  You could use `reshape2::melt` instead of `gather`, `merge` instead of `inner_join`, and `unique` instead of `distinct` to do the same thing if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Chris! Any chance you can explain the %>%, I've never seen that before and it throws an error in R. Thanks again.

Comment: You have to load `dplyr` for it to run. I've edited my answer to explain the operator and offer alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  This does not run on my real dataset unfortunately (returns "character(0)"). My real data has different column names in the example I provided; can you confirm that the only column names that need changed are "level_of_mean", "mean_value", and "source"? Do I need to change "level" and "value"?  (df1 in the example contained a "value" column, but neither dataframe contained a "level" column).  Also, my real strings have spaces in them, could this be why the code returns "character(0)"?

Comment: Yes that's true, but to save time on the join you might replace `select(-mean_value)` with `select(country, state, city, level_of_mean)` to remove any unneeded columns from `df2`

Comment: I don't know.  It's hard to anticipate what would happen with another dataset.  The answer I gave works for the example you provided.  If you could provide a reproducible example I could take a look.